# How to combine every looping axios post call response into one object?

Tags: javascript, promise

I am trying to send multiple post request in same URL with different payloads based on the earlier response and expecting one combined object as a final result to store into single variable for further usage. For this

```
for (let i = 0; i <= length; i++) {
        const postBody2 = {
          PropertyGuid: availableSpot[i].propertyguid,
          ZoneGuid: availableSpot[i].zoneguid,
          BookingStartUTC: "2022-11-10T18:15:00",
          BookingEndUTC: "2022-11-10T20:15:00",
          FilterAmenities: "",
          SpotGuid: null,
          UnitGuid: null,
        };
       
        let promises = [];
        promises.push(
          await axios
            .post(searchZoneUrl, postBody2, requestMetadata2)
            .then((response) => {
              // do something with response
              console.log(response.data);
            })
        );
```

This is my current output:
[image: Current output]

This is the expected output:
[image: Expected output]

Comment: `promises.push(await …)` makes no sense. That will never push a promise value into the array, but rather the fulfillment result (which in your case is `undefined` since the `.then()` callback doesn't `return` anything)

Comment: "*payloads based on the earlier response*" - that does not appear to happen in the code that you posted. Please [edit] your question to include your actual code.

Comment: "*This is my current output, this is the expected output*" - I fail to spot the difference (apart from the different formatting). What is the actual problem? Please explain in words, and post the desired result as text, not as a painting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a `Promise.all()` after your for loop. That will wait until all your http requests are done. It will then bundle them in array with all the responses.

```js
let promises = [];
for (let i = 0; i <= length; i++) {
  const postBody2 = {
    PropertyGuid: availableSpot[i].propertyguid,
    ZoneGuid: availableSpot[i].zoneguid,
    BookingStartUTC: "2022-11-10T18:15:00",
    BookingEndUTC: "2022-11-10T20:15:00",
    FilterAmenities: "",
    SpotGuid: null,
    UnitGuid: null,
  };

  promises.push(
    axios.post(searchZoneUrl, postBody2, requestMetadata2)
  );
}

Promise.all(promises).then((response) => console.log('response:', response))
```

The docs on the Promise API have different ways of settling an Array of promises you can have a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: @Rajesh Are you sure you've given the solution a try? When using `Promise.all()` the resolved promise will return an array of responses (`response` in the code will be an array): that matches your expected outcome.

Comment: @Terry Nothing is printing in the console when I used your code but post is happen as per the loop iteration

Comment: @Rajesh not sure how else I could help, the API documentation I have linked is exactly what you are looking for. The Promise.all resolves all promises and returns an Array.

Comment: @ End @Terry Now its working as expected, I moved code to a separate function and calls that function in a parent component.